# Time taken to remove Firebase Realtime Database Listener

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

My question is simple "how much time does it take to remove a listener?"

I am asking this because when I assign a ValueEventListener to a specific place in a real-time database and remove it after the work is done. Now, if still the changes are made to the same database location where the listener was working before being removed, I still get the values and that should not happen.

So, removing the ValueEventListener removes the listener instantaneously or after a while. If not then I might be doing something wrong with my code.

Along with ValueEventListener, I am also using callback flows.

```
// Repository Class
class TesterRepository {

    //Some Dao I have
    private val dao: GoodsDao = TODO()
    private val dataSource = TestDataSource()

    // Some State Flow
    private val _someStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
    private val someStateFlow = _someStateFlow.asStateFlow()

    private suspend fun someSyncFunction() {
        coroutineScope {
            launch { dao.getActiveTxnReferences().collect { _someStateFlow.value = it[0] } }
            launch {
                someStateFlow.collect {
                    if (it != null)
                        dataSource.remoteFirebaseDatabaseData(it).collectLatest { 
                            //data fed into some other room database dao.
                        }

                    if (it == "some logic"){
//                        Say I have a logic here which tells me the reference of where previous code was being run, i.e., I get the same exact value of "ref" which was used in datasource
                        dataSource.removeFirebaseSync(it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

// DataSource Class
class TestDataSource() {
    // Listener is saved here
    private var listener: ValueEventListener? = null

    suspend fun remoteFirebaseDatabaseData(ref: String) = callbackFlow {
       //Listener
        listener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                trySend(1)
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                trySend(2)
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }
        //Firebase Realtime Database call
        //the code keeps sync until a condition is med
        if (listener != null)
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(ref).addValueEventListener(listener!!)
        awaitClose {
            if (listener != null)
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(ref).removeEventListener(listener!!)
        }
    }

    //This code should remove the listener
    suspend fun removeFirebaseSync(ref: String) {
        
        //The code is run.
        if (listener != null)
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(ref).removeEventListener(listener!!)
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, after the remove event listener is run and I go on to realtime database console and change the values, the updates show up.

**Explanation of code::**

So There are 2 different Databases:

1. Represented by GoodsDao (Can change in Realtime)
2. Which we need to update using references contained in 1.

The first step gets the references from GoodsDao:

1. The References which are new should start listening to Realtime Database.
2. The References which are removed/absent, will take the path defined by `if (it == "some logic")` and remove the listeners.

- I am a little skeptical about whether to use suspend or not because `awaitClose {}` is a `suspend function call`

> Suspends the current coroutine until the channel is either closed or canceled and invokes the given block before resuming the coroutine.

`trySend` is the function being used to send data.
about `trySend`

> Immediately adds the specified element to this channel, if this doesn't violate its capacity restrictions, and returns the successful result. Otherwise, returns failed or closed result. This is synchronous variant of send, which backs off in situations when send suspends or throws.

Comment: You should use SingleValueEventLister for this

Comment: In case I have multiple value changes incoming, say 20 updates, but don't know when. In That case, SingleValueEventListener is not good. and ValueEventListener should be used

Comment: The listener is removed immediately, but there may still be some data that has already been received by the client that is still delivered to some types of clients. If you want to know what is going on in your specific case, edit your question to show a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: okay @FrankvanPuffelen will update it in a bit.

Comment: It's hard to follow the flow here, and we also can't see what your `trySend` function does. Can you try to simplify the code (e.g. do you really need `suspend` functions?), and add some logging so we can all look at the same flow.